# How to Show a String instead of address in textView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, arrays, memory-management

i am trying to get a random string from database i have tried to convert array in a String but when i click button i only get address can anyone help me how to show that string in my button action?

```
- (IBAction)randBtn:(id)sender {

        SendQuoteVC *svc= [[SendQuoteVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SendQuoteVC" bundle:nil];

        DBHandler *db =[[DBHandler alloc]init];
        arr =[db randomQuote];

        NSMutableString * show = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (NSObject * obj in arr)
        {
            [show appendString:[obj description]];
        }
        NSLog(@"The concatenated string is %@", show);

        NSString *rs =[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",show];
        svc.quote=rs;
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}
```

and my log message is

```
    2012-12-26 17:02:46.062 SendQuote[2281:c07] QUERY: SELECT * FROM quotes ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
2012-12-26 17:02:46.097 SendQuote[2281:c07] txtQuote is  (
    "<quoteDC: 0xa9a94c0>"
)
2012-12-26 17:02:46.100 SendQuote[2281:c07] rand is  (
    "<quoteDC: 0xa9a94c0>"
)
```

i have changed my user entity class to quoteDC class and my Db function is

```
-(NSMutableArray *)randomQuote{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString * sqlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM quotes ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"];
    sqlite3_stmt *ReturnStatement = (sqlite3_stmt *) [self getStatement: sqlStr];
    while (sqlite3_step(ReturnStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        @try
        {
            quoteDC *worddc = [[quoteDC alloc] init];

            NSString *userid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 0)];
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 1)];


            worddc.quote_id=[userid integerValue];
            worddc.quotes=name;
            [dataArray addObject:worddc];
        }
        @catch (NSException *ept) {
            NSLog(@"Exception in %s, Reason: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [ept reason]);
        }
    }
    return dataArray;


}
```

Comment: how are you storing the values retrieved from database ? Are you using object of any entity class ?

Comment: yes. i m using entity class..

Comment: If you paste your db method, then we will be ale to give more accurate answers

Comment: i edited my question and changed my entity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code makes the issue:

```
for (NSObject * obj in arr)
{
    [show appendString:[obj description]];
}
```

Because your entity class don't have a property like `description`.
Instead of this write:

```
for (quoteDC * obj in arr)
{
    [show appendString:[obj quotes]];
}
```

Comment: @QualityCoder: with pleasure :)

Answer (score 3):

the [db randomQuote] method returns an array of users not strings, you can typecast it to user object than get your desired property out of it!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your array is an array of objects of some `user` class rather than array of strings.
Hence the call to

```
[obj description]
```

is returning an object instead of a string.

You would need to override the description method in your `user` class, and return string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this i think it work for u...

```
    - (IBAction)randBtn:(id)sender {

    SendQuoteVC *svc= [[SendQuoteVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SendQuoteVC" bundle:nil];

    DBHandler *db =[[DBHandler alloc]init];
    arr =[db randomQuote];
    NSString *rs =(NSString *)arr;
    svc.quote=rs;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
   }
```

Comment: type cast arr as (nsstring *)arr in this line  NSString *rs =[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",arr];

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `for (NSObject * obj in arr)` use the object that is stored in `arr`.

I guess it is some DBHandler object. So use

```
for (DBHandler * dbh in arr){
    [show appendString:[dbh thePropertyYouWantToAppend]];
}
```